# Remove start of filename up to "_"

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, file-rename

So im a complete noob at batch programming, but I have this small program which will move files to specific folders based on filename:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
echo processing "%%a"
  for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%b in ("%%~nxa") do (
     move "%%a" "%%b" >nul
  )
)
pause
```

I want to extend this program to rename some files. 
The files that the program is moving are all named like: "0_107" or "151_107". which are moved to folders called "0" and "151" respectively.

Now I also want it to chop off everything before and including the underscore.
This means that "151_107" should still be moved to folder "151" but the file should be named "107".

Hope this makes sense - thanks in advance

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the FOR-parameter into a variable, then you can remove the leading part with the `*<text>=` syntax.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
    echo processing "%%a"
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%b in ("%%~nxa") do (
        set "name=%%~a"
        set "name=!name:*_=!"
        echo New destination %%b\!name!
        move "%%~a" "%%b\!name!" >nul
    )
)
```

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but how would that look when implemented into my piece of code ?